# sql server selecting sum of each record having same id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, cursor, sum

I am having table as below..

```
r_Id     Marks
1         25
1         25   
1         25
2         30
2         30
```

now i want a query in which sum of marks for each r_id should be calculated and result should be

```
r_Id     Sum
 1       75   
 2       60
```

Without  using cursor or looping in sql server 2008. Please help me out to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    r_Id, 
    SUM(Marks) AS [Sum] 
FROM 
    YourTable 
GROUP BY r_Id
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r_Id, 
    SUM(Marks) OVER(PARTITION BY r_Id) AS [Sum] 
FROM 
    YourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it

```
SELECT r_Id, SUM(Marks) AS [Sum] 
FROM SomeTable 
GROUP BY r_Id;
GO
```

I hope this helps.